# Prevent Netbios attacks?

Tags: security, netbios

What is the best way to prevent netbios hacker attacks and what can happen if my computer is successfully attacked? I am currently running windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your situation you can [disable NetBIOS](http://www.petri.co.il/disable_netbios_in_w2k_xp_2003.htm) (if you don't use it on a local network) or put a router between your network and the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

You could [block NetBIOS connections](http://searchwinit.techtarget.com/news/article/0,289142,sid1_gci904130,00.html).